# sql query in the SqlDataAdapter()

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net windows form application. I have loaded names of all the tables present in a database into a combobox.

Now i need to display the contents of the selected table name.

Normally we use

SqlDataAdapter adp= new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from employee", con);

This works fine. but instead of explicitly giving table name  i.e employee
i need to set it to combobox1.selected item.

I have given like this its not working:
string filename= combobox1.selecteditem;
SqlDataAdapter adp= new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from filename", con);

How can I select filename dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string concatenation, if you're not afraid of SQL injection:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " +  combobox1.selecteditem, con);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should look like:

```
string filename= combobox1.selecteditem.ToString();
SqlDataAdapter adp= new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from "+filename, con);
```